# Return the n-th element of a list

Tags: list, recursion, elixir

I want to find the n-th element of my `list[1,2,3]`. I want to choose element 2, using recursion.

I have already found the length using:

```
def module T do
  def main do
    len([1,2,3])
  end
  def len([]), do: 0
  def len([h|t]), do: 1+len(t)
end
```

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this, including `Enum.at/2` or `Enum.reduce_while/3` but I suppose you are asking specifically about how to solve this with recursion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's def a library function for that (`Enum.at/2`), but if you want your own implementation:

```
# Little extra to handle negative positions (from the end of the list)
# element_at([1,2,3], -1) == 3
def element_at(list, n) when n < 0 do
  element_at(Enum.reverse(list), -n - 1)
end

def element_at([], _), do: nil
def element_at([h | _t], 0), do: h
def element_at([_h | t], n), do: element_at(t, n - 1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to accept the answer if suits the question :)

Comment: I’d add `def element_at(list, n) when n < 0, do: h |> :lists.reverse() |> element_at(-n)` to gracefully handle `element_at(list, -1)`.

Comment: I added two underscores to avoid compile hints because of unused variables.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to implement it by yourself. Otherwise there are a lot of functions you my use in the [Enum](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) and [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) modules.

```
defmodule Test do
  def nth_element(list, n) when is_list(list) and is_integer(n) do
    case {list, n} do
      {[], _}            -> nil 
      {[element | _], 0} -> element
      {[_ | rest], _}    -> nth_element(rest, n - 1)
    end 
  end 
  def nth_element(_, _), do: nil 
end
```

Argument `n` of the nth_element function is the index (it starts with 0) of the element you are looking for. If the list is empty or it has no element at the given index, it returns nil. Otherwise the function uses pattern matching to get an element and the rest of the list. If you are looking for the first element (index = n = 0) then it will return the element. If you are looking for an element at a higher index, the function will be called recursively with the rest of the list and the given index minus one element. This way you find the element you want in the recursion if n == 0. In the case the list is empty but n >= 0 the recursion ends, because of the first function definition and it returns nil.

I saved the module in test.ex. Execution:

```
$ iex
iex(1)> c "test.ex"
iex(2)> Test.nth_element([1,2,5], 0)
# => 1
iex(3)> Test.nth_element([1,2,5], 1)
# => 2
iex(4)> Test.nth_element([1,2,5], 2)
# => 5
iex(5)> Test.nth_element([1,2,5], 3)
# => nil
```

Comment: Mixing clauses and `case` to achieve the same goal is an antipattern. The answer by @IvanYurov is way more straightforward.

Comment: Your are right, but for me it looks a bit more well-arranged to be clear what's the intend of the code. A personal felling only.

Comment: Then use `case {list, n} do ⏎ {[], _} -> ... ⏎ {_, 0} -> ... ⏎ {_, n} -> ... ⏎ end` :)

Comment: Ok, I agree. What about the guard clauses and the resulting catch all definition?

Comment: Now it looks consistent to me; I wonder how this is compared to several function clauses in terms of performance (I’d wild guess it does not differ much.)